# Match features that are spatially similar with ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'm hoping there might be a way to match features from one feature class to features of another feature class that are the most spatially similar. I have two datasets representing the same thing that were created by two different organizations.
[image]

Now I need to get information form each of their attribute tables and learn how they relate. I've seen 10.2 has [Similarity Search](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005p0000005m000000) that looks promising but I'm working with 10.1.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I've used to fix those with the spatial adjustment toolbar - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000030000000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi Emil. The technique is called "conflation" and unfortunately ESRI did a lot of development in conflation for 10.2. There is even a toolbox in 10.2 fully devoted to your problem.

[image]

I would say, try using a spatial join, or using the "Attribute Transfer Tool" in the Spatial Adjustment toolbar in ArcMap.

[image]

[image]

Or if you're really ambitious depending on the level of effort, you can invest in a software called [MapMerger](http://www.mapmerger.com/)!

Comment: "Unfortunately" because he's on 10.1 and not 10.2. Your other option would be to use one of the Near tools.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001n000000
And then use a standard join based on a unique ID (like OBJECTID) to transfer attributes.