# How to Find similar geometries?

Tags: arcpy, similarity

I'm looking for an algorithm in Python or a combination of arcgis tools to find similar (but not identical) entities between 2 different feature classes.

I attach a picture to the illustration.

[image: example:]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Similar question to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153115/match-features-that-are-spatially-similar-with-arcgis

Comment: Else solution please?